# SMO - Transfer - Cannot get the event handlers to fire

Tags: c#, smo

I am using SMO (C#) to copy data from one table to another, with the following code:

```
public static void PopulateStagingTable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Copy data to staging table...");

            string databaseConnection = "Data Source=---; Initial Catalog=---; Integrated Security=SSPI;";

            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(databaseConnection)));
            Database database = server.Databases["ProcessData"];
            Table table = database.Tables["....", "dbo"];

            Transfer t = new Transfer(database);

            t.CopyAllTables = false;
            t.CopyAllObjects = false;
            t.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = false;
            t.CopySchema = false;
            t.CopyData = true;
            t.ObjectList.Add(table);
            t.Options.WithDependencies = false;
            t.BatchSize = 5000;

            t.DestinationServer = "ODSProduction";
            t.DestinationDatabase = "StagingPBG";
            t.CreateTargetDatabase = false;

            t.DataTransferEvent += new DataTransferEventHandler(DataTransferEventHandler);
            t.DiscoveryProgress += new ProgressReportEventHandler(ProgressEventHandler);
            t.ScriptingProgress += new ProgressReportEventHandler(ScriptingProgressEventHandler);

            t.TransferData();
        }

        private static void DataTransferEventHandler(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        private static void ProgressEventHandler(object sender, ProgressReportEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.Write("Progress {0} of {1} . . . {2} \n", args.TotalCount, args.Total, args.Current);
        }

        public static void ScriptingProgressEventHandler(object sender, ProgressReportEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.Write("Progress {0} of {1} . . . {2} \n", args.TotalCount, args.Total, args.Current);
        }
```

All of this works great except the Discovert and Scripting event handlers never fire. I'd like to update the user with the progress being made as the transfer operation proceeds but the events don't fire. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: There is not enough code here to diagnose the problem. Clearly the events are correctly attached, but it's obvious that they don't fire. Why they don't fire is a mystery because we don't see the code as to why.